# Use previous and next buttons to navigate items in a drop down list

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to create previous and next buttons on a page to navigate through items in a drop down list. Clicking next should select the next item in the DDL and clicking previous should go to the previous item. 
Here's something I've attempted for the next button but it just takes me to the last row.

```
protected void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int currentSelection = DDL.SelectedIndex;
    for (int i = currentSelection; i < DDL.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        string nextSelection = (DDL.Items[i].ToString());           
        DDL.SelectedValue = nextSelection;
    }
}
```

Comment: what happens when its in the last index? it select first item?

Comment: @Mohammad, no it selects the last item.

Comment: we were both answering together...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looping through all the items in the list until you get to the last one, and selecting each item individually until the loop exits. Drop a breakpoint inside that loop and debug to see what I mean.

You don't need any looping here at all. What you'd want instead would be simply:

```cs
int nextIndex = DDL.SelectedIndex + 1;

if (nextIndex + 1 >= DDL.Items.Count)
    return; // We're on the last item, do nothing (or whatever you like)

DDL.SelectedValue = DDL.Items[nextIndex].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You easily can change selected value by its index so you don't need change it by its value.

```
int i = ddl.SelectedIndex;

if (i+1!=ddl.Items.Count)
{
    ddl.SelectedIndex = i + 1;
}
else
{
    ddl.SelectedIndex = i;
}
```

as you said in comment it wont change index if the current index is the last one.